# unicode char value

Tags: c++, excel, unicode, char, collation

Question: What is the correct order of Unicode extended symbols by value?

If I excel sort a list of Unicode chars the order is different than if I use the excel "=code()" and sort by those values. The purpose is that I want to measure the distance between chars, for example a-b = 1 and &-% = 1; when sorted with the excel sort function, two chars that are ordered within three appear to have values that are 134 away.

Also, some char symbols are blank in excel and several are found twice with 'find' and are two different symbols - and a couple are not found at all. Please explain the details of these 'special' chars.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

sample code:

```
int charDist = abs(alpha[index] - code[0]);
```

EDIT:
To figure out the UNICODE values in c++ vs2008 I ran each code as a comparison from code 1 to code 255 against code 1

```
cout << mem << " code " << key << " is " << abs(key[0] - '') << " from " << endl;
```

In the brackets is a black happy face that this website does not have the font for but the command window does, in vs2008 it looks like a half-post | with the right half of a T. Excel leaves a blank.

The following Unicodes are not handled in c++ vs2008 with the std library and #include 
9, 10, 13, 26, 34, 44,

And, the numerical 'distance' for codes 1 through 127 are correct, but at 128 the distance skips an extra and is one further away for some reason. Then from 128 to 255 the distance reverses and becomes closer; 255 is 2 away from 1 ''

It'd be nice if these followed something more logical and were just 1 through 255 without hiccups or skips and reversals, and 255-1 = 254 but hey, what do I know.

EDIT2: I found it - without the absolute - the collation for UNIFORMAT is 128 to 255 then 1 to 127 and yields 1 to 255 with the 6 skips for 9, 10, 13, 26, 34, 44 that are garbage. That was not intuitive. In the new order 128->255,1->127 the strange skip from 127 to 128 is clearer, it is because there is no 0 so the value is missing between 255 and 1.

SOLUTION: make my own hashtable with values for each symbol and do not rely on c++ std library or vs2008 to provide the UNIFORMAT values since they are not correct for measuring the char distance outside of several specific subsets of UNIFORMAT.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me

Comment: Sorting arbitrary Unicode data is a tremendously complex problem. It's not as simple as sorting the numeric value of ASCII characters, due to weird sorting rules in some languages (eg. in Spanish, *ch* and *ll* are both treated as one letter for sorting purposes). What's the problem you are really trying to solve?

Comment: Ordering of codepoints in a character set is usually [called `collation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation), not edit-distance (which would be [Hamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), e.g.)

Comment: the term 'collation' is a good starting point. So I need to understand collation to allow measuring char distance as a function of a Hamming algorithm that includes the full range of the expanded Unicode char set. More information is appreciated.

Comment: In response to 'several are found twice'; it may be worth noting that some Unicode 'glyphs' can be represented by multiple Unicode 'code points', or even as a *combination of multiple* code points.  For example, most European accented characters can have their own code point, but also can be generated by combining the code point for the unaccented character with a special code point that means 'add an accent'.  Another example is the omega glyph, which is represented by both a Greek alphabet code point and by a 'mathematical symbols' code point.

Comment: this is tagged C++ because that is the language I am using to compare char distance (collation distance?). It sounds like I have two choices 1) trial and error find the order in c++ by checking each symbol against a comparison symbol x0 - x1, x0-x2 ... x0 - xn 2) open this discussion to the X problem of using UNICODE symbols to represent with a more compact string than possible with an alpha numeric code such as G5010 -> G%$ and simplifying overhead position counters when the set is less than 255

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode doesn't have a defined sort (or collation) order.  When Excel sorts, it's using tables based on the currently selected language.  For example, someone using Excel in English mode may get different sorting results that someone using Excel in Portuguese.

There are also issues of normalization.  With Unicode, one "character" doesn't necessarily correspond to one value.  Some characters can be represented in different ways.  For example, a capital omega can be coded as a Greek letter or as a symbol for representing units of electrical resistance.  In some languages, a single character may be composed from several consecutive values.

The blank values probably correspond to glyphs that you don't have any font coverage for.  Some systems use so-called "Unicode fonts" which have a large percentage of the glyphs you need for every script.  Windows tends to switch fonts on the fly when the current font doesn't have a necessary glyph.  Neither approach will have every glyph necessary.  Also, some Unicode values don't encode to a visible glyph (e.g., there are many different kinds of spaces in Unicode), some values act more like ASCII-style controls codes (e.g., paragraph separator or bidi controls), and some values only make sense when they combine with another character, like many of the "combining" accents.

So there's not an answer you're going to be satisfied with.  Perhaps if you gave more information about what you're ultimately trying to do, we could suggest a different approach.

Comment: @Adrian_McCarthy, thank you, this confirms my suspicions that excel was sorting based on the language. In a best case scenario I'd like to have 999 symbols and I think this will be available soon. For now 255 works for the 'real' scenarios that actually exist in my case. I read the symbols into a hash and associated strings so i can hash from a string to the single symbol and use these until print out when they are hashed back into the string. I use * ? and z for wilds.

Comment: in excel, countif(255 char, this char) for * returns 255 char count - usually * is the wildcard for 'all' and I assume that excel recognizes thai and so returns all char as a match? Same for ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want to do in Excel without limiting your approach significantly.

By experimentation, the Code function will never return a value higher than 255. If you use any unicode text that cannot be generated via this VBA Code, it will be interpreted as a question mark (?) or 63.

```
For x = 1 To 255
    Cells(x, 1).Value = Chr(x)
Next
```

You should be able to determine the difference using Code. But if the character doesn't fall in that realm, you'll need to go outside of Excel, because even VBA will convert any other Unicode characters to the question mark(?) or 63.

Comment: @Daniel_Cook, thank you. I should have been clearer that I used excel to form a csv file with a column of UNICODE symbols and a column of the string I wanted to associate with each symbol, for example, "003" == '3'; your advice helped in that I will try similar code in C++ to find which symbols are recognized and the collated value of each.